# SQL Update with multiple INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables,

```
SELECT [SHADOW_ID]
      ,[DATA]
      ,[TSN]
      ,[HEALTH_PLAN_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID]
FROM [stbl834]
```

and

```
SELECT [HEALTH_PLAN_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID]
      ,[TSN]
FROM [uvwCLIENT_HEALTH_PLAN]
```

Right now HEALTH_PLAN_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID are all set to NULL in stbl834, I need to fetch these values from uvwCLIENT_HEALTH_PLAN based on different TSN values from stbl834. Is there a way to do this using JOIN statements? I need to avoid any sort of loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run a select

```
SELECT * 
FROM [stbl834] A
INNER JOIN [uvwCLIENT_HEALTH_PLAN] B ON A.TSN = B.TSN
```

and verify that you have correct number of rows and that the values in the columns match. this would ensure that you have a correct join key. If this looks correct use the below update

```
UPDATE [stbl834]
SET [HEALTH_PLAN_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID] = B.[HEALTH_PLAN_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID]
FROM [stbl834] A
INNER JOIN [uvwCLIENT_HEALTH_PLAN] B ON A.TSN = B.TSN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select HEALTH_PLAN_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID, TSN
from stbl834 left join uvwCLIENT_HEALTH_PLAN
on stbl834.TSN=uvwCLIENT_HEALTH_PLAN.TSN
```

Do you need to insert them into stbl834? If so --

```
update stbl834
set HEALTH_PLAN_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID = uvwCLIENT_HEALTH_PLAN.HEALTH_PLAN_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID
from stbl834 left join uvwCLIENT_HEALTH_PLAN
on stbl834.TSN=uvwCLIENT_HEALTH_PLAN.TSN
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do this for any RDBMS that does not support the `UPDATE..FROM` syntax:

```
UPDATE stbl834 
SET    health_plan_category_value_id = (SELECT health_plan_category_value_id 
                                        FROM   uvwclient_health_plan 
                                        WHERE uvwclient_health_plan.tns = stbl834.tns)
```

This solution is SQL Ansi compatible, meaning it will work for *any* RDBMS. Please make sure the sub-query (`SELECT`) will only return record value for a given TNS, or else you will have to ensure that by using `TOP` or `LIMIT` (whatever is supported by your RDBMS).

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this too, this might serve your purpose.

```
update  stbl834
set stbl834.HEALTH_PLAN_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID= uvwCLIENT_HEALTH_PLAN.HEALTH_PLAN_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID
inner join uvwCLIENT_HEALTH_PLAN.TSN=HEALTH_PLAN_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID.TSN
```